# Cant run curl with arguments from .desktop file

Tags: bash, .desktop, curl

***I've been trying to get a .desktop file to open a new full screen terminal, run "curl wttr.in"*** (wttr.in is a weather forecast service that works well with the terminal) ***, and leave the window open.*** I have managed to get other commands to run in a new full screen terminal from a .desktop file, but "curl wttr.in" doesn't work. The closest I have gotten to making it work is a .sh script with the following contents, which (executed on its own) does *exactly* what I want perfectly:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal --window --maximize -- ./wttr.sh
$SHELL
```

wttr.sh contains

```
curl wttr.in
sleep 60
```

But even putting the path to that script (which I did make executable) as the Exec of a .desktop opens a full screen terminal with the following message and nothing else:

> "There was an error creating the child process for this terminal Failed to execute child process "./wttr.sh": Failed to execve: No such file or directory"

I've tried doing it the more normal ways, like putting the program right at the end of the gnome-terminal thing, but that hasnt worked either.

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

This is my first time making one of these posts, so if there's something I could do better, feel free to let me know.

Comment: You've not told us your OS/release details, but why use a *relative* path (ie. `./wttr.sh` relies on $PWD being correct otherwise "No such file" errors are to be expected), why not define the path fully?

Comment: @guiverc originally I was doing that by just keeping them in the same directory because ./someotherdirectory wasn't working... I just realized the dot is part of the path. That's an embarrassing mistake. It works now! Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had misunderstood what the dot in ./ did, writing out the full path in both the .sh and the desktop file fixed the issue.

Comment: Good Question.  Good Answer.  Welcome to AskUbuntu.